# Using BERT Q&A model (SQUAD) to answer questions from a dataset

Tags: bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering, squad

I am developing a custom BERT Q&A model (in the same format as SQUAD) with a view to pose questions to a dataset for an answer (the dataset is large collection of reports).

Is it possible to use the BERT model directly on the dataset, or would I ideally need to have a preceding similarity/vector search step that returns nearest neighbours to the query, which are then fed to the BERT model as context?

Appreciate any guidance!